# How to start terminal in which bash is running with adjusted environment variables?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, xubuntu, xfce4

I'm using Xubuntu with XFCE.

I would like to write a bash script which opens a new tab in the xfce4-terminal. In this tab, the bash should be running with an altered `PATH` environment variable.

Currently, the shell script looks like that:

```
xfce4-terminal \
    --tab \
    --title=GCC \
    --command 'bash'
```

It is opening a new bash-tab in the terminal just like it should. However, I would additionally like this environment variable to be set:

```
export PATH=/home/manuel/toolchains/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4/bin:$PATH
```

I suppose it's possible to provide this command as argument to the `bash` command in my shell script. However, even after studying the man page I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**env**](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html) command.

> `env` runs a command with a modified environment. Synopses:
>
> ```
> env [option]... [name=value]... [command [args]...]
> ```

So you in your specific case you should run the following:

```
xfce4-terminal \
    --tab \
    --title=GCC \
    --command "env PATH=/home/manuel/toolchains/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4/bin:$PATH bash"
```

Notice that I have used double quotes (`"`) instead of single (`'`), because I needed the value of the old `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: It worked! Could you also tell me what to do, if I would like the opened bash shell to execute (or, preferably, `source`) a shell script immediately after opening?

Comment: @Multisync, there might be a better way, but this is what I was able to find out right now. The ["Invoking Bash"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html) section of the manual suggests running it with the `--init-file` or `--rcfile` option. Since `~/.bashrc` is going to be skipped, you might want to source it at the beginning of your script, so you don't miss it. So you would do something like `--init-file custom.sh` and at the beginning of `custom.sh` do `source ~/.bashrc`.